# Pass window.innderWidth in initial GET request

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

Assuming I have server-side rendered app with responsive styling based on `window.innerWidth`, how do I pass client's screen size in initial GET request for `index.html`, so that I can prepare on server and respond with appropriately styled page?

Consider the [following example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-nz37be):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export const App = () => {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(globalThis?.innerWidth);

  useEffect(() => {
    const updateWidth = () => setWidth(window.innerWidth);

    window.addEventListener('resize', updateWidth);

    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', updateWidth);
  });

  return <p>Your window is {width}px wide</p>;
};
```

While server is rendering html for above component it has no clue about `.innerWidth` (hence, `width`) and, most probably, corresponding part of the `<p>` will be left empty until react kicks-in client side, triggering `useState()` and initiating `width` with `globalThis` (= `window` now) `.innerWidth`.

So, my point is how do I pass `window.innerWidth` (which browser, apparently, knows when it requests index.js) insider my GET request, so that I can use it server side, e.g. with:

```js
export function getServerSidePorps(context) {

  // some logic here, extracting window width from context.req

  return {
    props: {width},
  };
}
```

Comment: So send the header along with the fetch calls you are making to get the content?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it, because the browser width exists only on the client side. It's impossible to use it on the server side, before rendering the page.

Comment: Since there's obviously no `window` server-side, there can't be `window.innerWidth` neither. I'm aware of that and I'm not attempting to use that. What I'm trying to figure out is slightly different: when browser requests index.html from server it already knows which screen it has at its disposal, so if browser could give a _hint_ about that (using HTTP-header or query param, whatever) to server, the latter could prepare appropriate html.